# Change limits of a Query without executing it again in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Is it possible to change the limits of a Query without executing it again.

Here is my code:

```
$this->db->select("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS e.emp_no, e.birth_date, e.first_name, e.last_name, e.gender, e.hire_date, t.title, s.salary, d.dept_name", FALSE)
            ->from('employees AS e')
            ->join('titles AS t', 'e.emp_no = t.emp_no')
            ->join('salaries AS s', 't.emp_no = s.emp_no')
            ->join('dept_emp AS de', 's.emp_no = de.emp_no')
            ->join('departments AS d', 'de.dept_no = d.dept_no')
            ->join('dept_manager AS dm', 'd.dept_no = dm.dept_no')
            ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order)
            ->group_by('e.emp_no')
            ->where('t.title', $title)
                        ->limit($limit, $offset);


    $ret['rows'] = $q->get()->result();
```

I am using pagination so if I keep loading a query that return about 100,000 rows it slows down the return.

I wanted to make it faster by running the query once then changing the limit dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit doesn't slow down your application. "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" does. It's known fact that it can slow down a query, and i mean SLOW. Check this post for benchmarks and explanation of how it works: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Comment: Thank you for the response, this makes more sense. Is there an alternative way to count the total number of results to use for pagination?

Comment: Becwuse you have a group by in your query... i supose you need the unique cout for e.emp_no... so you can use: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e.emp_no)..... Shouldn't take more then few ms on a huge db.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this has nothing to do with Code Igniter or PHP.  It would depend on your database.

From there, I believe it will depend on the query.  If you have a normal `SELECT` query with no sort, then MySQL at least will stop once it has reached the limit.  The data beyond that limit is not available.

Perhaps if you had a subquery, and limited with the outer query, the results of the subquery could be cached, depending on your server configuration and how volatile your data is.  You would have poor performance at first, as the whole query would need to finish, but subsequent queries could be faster.